# $concatArrays not working on existing multi array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this sample document with key values set to be array of arrays.

```
{ _id: 1, items: [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ] }
```

Here is my aggregate function

```
db.collection.aggregate([

   { $project: { items: { $concatArrays: "$items" } } }

])
```

Result should be:

```
{ _id: 1, items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
```

However results are:

```
{ _id: 1, items: [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ] }
```

Is there is another way to achieve the required output? I know I that I could use `lodash` `_.flattenDeep(items)`, but I'm looking for mongodb solution.

Here is my [mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wc9SGEZ2mQ_)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "items": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$items",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$this", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vIe8_eVcIRU)

Comment: While this produces the desired result, performance can be a major problem using this approach if the amount of arrays to concatenate together is important.

Comment: For reference, this approach is used in the [official docs for $reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#array-concatenation)

Answer (score 5):

I've seen you already got your answer but I'll briefly explain why this behaviour is happening for anyone curios.

This is actually a "feature" of Mongo, there is an open [feature change request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31991) you can track. but first let's understand what's [causing](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31786?focusedCommentId=1724156&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1724156) it:

> There are a class of expressions which accept multiple arguments, expressed as an array. (In the code, these inherit from ExpressionNary.) For any such n-ary expression, which I will call $nary, the syntax {$nary: "$myArg"} is simply a shorthand for {$nary: ["$myArg"]}. These two expression are identical in meaning.

So this unique class of expressions include many operators, one of them is [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/). Mongo's expression languages just parses any '$arg' as ['$arg'] for these operators.
This is why the 'unexpected' behaviour happens when you used the `$dups` expression but does not happen when you explicitly write the same values.